# Erro ao declarar constantes em Java

Tags: java, constantes

Iniciei agora meus estudos em Java e estou com um problema ao declarar uma constante:

```
class Ex007
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float comprimento, raio = 9f;
        public static final float PI = 1.1416f;
        comprimento = raio * PI * 2f;
        System.out.println("Comprimento: " + comprimento);
    }
}
```

O seguinte erro aparece:

```
ex007.java:6: error: illegal start of expression
        public static final float PI = 1.1416f;
        ^
ex007.java:7: error: <identifier> expected
        comprimento = raio * PI * 2f;
                   ^
ex007.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println("Comprimento: " + comprimento);
                          ^
ex007.java:8: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.println("Comprimento: " + comprimento);
                           ^
ex007.java:10: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
5 errors
```

Se nesse código eu retirar o:

```
public static final
```

o PI se torna uma variável normal e o código funciona normalmente. Todos os tutoriais sobre constantes mostram que para declarar basta colocar o código:

```
public static final float NOME_CONSTANTE VALOR;
```

Mas isso não funciona aqui, tentei compilar no replt.it para ver se não era minha JDK e lá também não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade é o seguinte, como voce esta no metodo main, voce nao pode definir atributos publicos, e por esta dentro de um metodo(main) voce nao pode definir atributos de classe(static). Ou seja, se voce tirar o public e o static vai funcionar.
Outra questao é nessa parte:
float comprimento, raio = 9f;
Voce esta tentando informar 2 variaveis em simultaneo: comprimento e raio, mas voce deve informar uma por vez.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!